# Gradle sync failed: C:\Users\DG\AndroidStudioProjects\Calci-app\Calci-app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-studio-import

I am a newbie in Android Studio and I copied an Android Studio project from a pen drive in my Laptop and tried to run it on my laptop and I am getting this error in Android Studio. Given below is my build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
dependencies {
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools/sdklib
compile group: 'com.android.tools', name: 'sdklib', version: '25.1.2'

compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile project(':app')
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'Calci-app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
}
}
repositories {
maven { url 'android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout' }
}
```

I don't know how to fix this error. Please help me..

here is my androidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.facilitydoor.app.facilitydoor">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".ApplicationWrapper"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Door_Wallet"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SubSubCategory"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PaymentGateway"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TermsOfUse"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PrivacyPolicy"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutUs"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactUs"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CitySelect"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ServicesExpandedFromView"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Picker"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewAllCategory"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ServicesExpanded"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Subcategory"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BookServices"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".AddressStore"           
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        ></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Thankyou"
        android:label="Thankyou"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
  sourceSets {
      main {
          manifest.srcFile 'Calci-app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml'
      }
  }
}
```

Add this code to your Gradle